# Why do Linux commands not work properly on Android?

Tags: adb, linux, shell, command-line

```
> adb shell
sh-4.1$ ls -F
-F: No such file or directory
```

`-F` switch works fine on my Ubuntu.

Why doesn't it work on Android? Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most shell commands in Android are not GNU versions or a POSIX-compliant implementation, they are either from Toolbox or Busybox and mostly stripped down versions.

A lot of commands in `/system/bin` are symlinks to `/system/toolbox`. I haven't found much documentation about it, just the source at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/jb-mr1-release/toolbox/

Busybox is another implementation of several common shell commands, with more commands and features than the default Toolbox. It's used on other embedded systems too, and some bootable GNU/Linux CDs, so you may already be familiar with it. Because it's open-source, there are several installers available on Google Play: just search for "Busybox".

Comment: There is a guide at https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator/wiki/Android-Shell-Command-Reference

Comment: Strictly speaking, GNU userland command tools are not "original", they were designed based on existing Unix command tools and POSIX.